# Why std::forward return a rvalue when transferring a lvalue?

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference, perfect-forwarding

It is said that std::forward() *perfectly* forwards a lvalue to lvalue, and rvalue to rvalue. But the code below seems to show a different conclusion?

when I run the code below

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
 public:
    int x;

    A() {x = 0;}
    explicit A(int x) : x(x) {}

    A& operator= (A&& other) {
        std::cout << " && ="  << std::endl;
        x = other.x;
    }

    A& operator= (const A& other) {
        std::cout << " & ="  << std::endl;
        x = other.x;
    }
};

int main() {
    A p1(1), p2, p3;
    p2 = p1;
    p3 = std::forward<A>(p1);
    return 0;
}
```

The result is:

```
 & =
 && =
```

it seems that `std::forward<A>(p1)` forwards `p1` as rvalue.

The source code of std::forward() is:

```
  /**
   *  @brief  Forward an lvalue.
   *  @return The parameter cast to the specified type.
   *
   *  This function is used to implement "perfect forwarding".
   */
  template<typename _Tp>
    constexpr _Tp&&
    forward(typename std::remove_reference<_Tp>::type& __t) noexcept
    { return static_cast<_Tp&&>(__t); }

  /**
   *  @brief  Forward an rvalue.
   *  @return The parameter cast to the specified type.
   *
   *  This function is used to implement "perfect forwarding".
   */
  template<typename _Tp>
    constexpr _Tp&&
    forward(typename std::remove_reference<_Tp>::type&& __t) noexcept
    {
      static_assert(!std::is_lvalue_reference<_Tp>::value, "template argument"
            " substituting _Tp is an lvalue reference type");
      return static_cast<_Tp&&>(__t);
    }
```

gdb shows that when running `p3 = std::forward<A>(p1);`, it steps into the first function `forward(typename std::remove_reference<_Tp>::type& __t) noexcept` and returns a value of type `A &&`

```
(gdb) p __t
$2 = (std::remove_reference<A>::type &) @0x7fffffffd1cc: {
  x = 1
}
(gdb) p static_cast<_Tp&&>(__t)
$3 = (A &&) @0x7fffffffd1cc: {
  x = 1
}
```

I am totally confused. Would you please explain what happened when calling std::forward()? If `std::forward<A>(p1)` forwards `p1` as rvalue, then what's the difference of std::forward and std::move?

Comment: `forward` is just a conditional move. If the template argument is `T &` it does nothing, and otherwise it acts as a `std::move`. It's intended to be used with forwarding references. When outside of a template, there's no point in using it, since you can unconditionally `std::move` or not move.

Comment: `std::forward` is meant to be used with reference collapsing, which is how universal references work. It doesn't make sense to pass it a non-reference type, it isn't an expected use case for that function. Try `std::forward<A&>`, which will give you the desired behaviour, which is also equivalent to not using `std::forward` at all. It is basically meant to deduced whether or not to `std::move` should be used based on what kind of reference a template argument is.

Answer (score 2):

> If `std::forward<A>(p1)` forwards p1 as rvalue, then what's the difference of `std::forward` and `std::move`?

The difference is that `std::forward<A&>(p1)` returns an lvalue, and `std::move` does not.

You're misusing `std::forward`. Passing a constant template type argument is pointless. They're useful when a function template has a forwarding reference argument whose type is deduced from function argument: Example:

```
template<class T>
void foo(T&& ref) {
    T t = std::forward<T>(ref); // copy or move

...
foo(p1); // T is deduced as A&
```